# Difference Between np.random.uniform() and uniform() using built-in python packages

Tags: python, numpy, random, uniform

I'm using `np.random.uniform()` to generate a number in a class. Surprisingly, when I run the code, I can't see any expected changes in my results. On the other hand, when I use `uniform()` from python built-in packages, I see the changes in my results and that's obviously normal.

Are they really the same or is there anything tricky in their implementation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You aren't seeing any changes with `np.random.uniform()` or you do see some but just not what was expected?

Comment: I don't see any changes with respect to numpy packages and it always show me the same result e.g. in graph theory imagine to use a random number to connect some nodes with edges and we use this random number to choose the desired one but when you run it, it always shows you the same graph but on the contrary, the the built-in python uniform() always shows different results in each run.

Comment: Are you setting a seed first?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it but it doesn't matter if I don't use a seed or change the seed number. I checked it several times.

Comment: Show some actual codec and results.  We shouldn't have to guess the details.

Comment: It is possible that other parts of your project are in the background using numpy and setting the seed.

Comment: See https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html.

Comment: Particularly the section on `numpy.random.*`.

Comment: Try `rng = np.random.default_rng()` then generate random numbers using `rng.uniform()`. @MehdiHosseini

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one module, say, `blankpaper.py`, with only two lines of code

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(420)
```

Then, in your main script, execute

```
import numpy as np 
import blankpaper 

print(np.random.uniform())
```

You should be getting exactly the same numbers.

When a module or library sets `np.random.seed(some_number)`, it is **global**. Behind the `numpy.random.*` functions is an instance of the `global RandomState` generator, emphasis on the `global`.

It is very likely that something that you are importing is doing the aforementioned.

Change the main script to

```
import numpy as np
import blankpaper

rng = np.random.default_rng()
print(rng.uniform())
```

and you should be getting new numbers each time.

`default_rng` is a constructor for the random number class, `Generator`. As stated in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator),

> This function does not manage a default global instance.

In reply to the question, "[a]re you setting a seed first?", you said

> Yes, I'm using it but it doesn't matter if I don't use a seed or
> change the seed number. I checked it several times.

Imagine we redefine `blankpaper.py` to contain the lines

```
import numpy as np

def foo():
    np.random.seed(420)
    print("I exist to always give you the same number.")
```

and suppose your main script is

```
import numpy as np
import blankpaper

np.random.seed(840)

blankpaper.foo()
print(np.random.uniform())
```

then you should be getting the same numbers as were obtained from executing the first main script (top of the answer).

In this case, the setting of the seed is hidden in one of the functions in the `blankpaper` module, but the same thing would happen if `blankpaper.foo` were a class and `blankpaper.foo`'s `__init__()` method set the seed.

So this setting of the global seed can be quite "hidden".

Note also that the above also applies for the functions in the [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random)

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a
> hidden instance of the random.Random class. You can instantiate your
> own instances of Random to get generators that don’t share state.

So when `uniform()` from the `random` module was generating different numbers each time for you, it was very likely because you nor some other module set the seed shared by functions from the `random` module.

In both `numpy` and `random`, if your class or application wants to have it's own state, create an instance of `Generator` from `numpy` or `Random` from `random` (or `SystemRandom` for cryptographically-secure randomness). This will be something you can pass around within your application. It's methods will be the functions in the `numpy.random` or `random` module, only they will have their own state (unless you explicitly set them to be equal).

Finally, I am not claiming that this is exactly what is causing your problem (I had to make a few inferences since I cannot see your code), but this is a very likely reason.

Any questions/concerns please let me know!